# Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcut to open context menu on document tab

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a keyboard shortcut to show the context menu for a document tab - same as document tab right click?

Note: not the same as shift + F10 which brings up the main context menu.

thanks

Answer (score 29):

I was looking for this thing for quite some time and I accidently opened this menu today using my keyboard. The command is "Window.ShowDockMenu". The default key binding (at least in VS 2012) is "alt + -".

Comment: This works for both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. Use with conjunction Ctrl+F6 which tabs throught the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

What, in particular, are you looking to be able to do?

By default I don't think that there is one to open the document tab context window, but you can map custom shortcuts for a lot of the actions that are available under this context window.

To map a custom shortcut for `Close All`, for example, navigate to:

```
Tools > Options > Keyboard
```

Enter `Window.CloseAllDocuments` in the `Show commands containing:` textbox, and choose a shortcut. There are thousands of commands here, so chances are you'll find one that does what you want.

Also check out [this plugin](http://blog.tabsstudio.com/2011/03/), which might have some of the features you're looking for.

Comment: I looked at this plugin and the productivity tools. I'm just looking for a keyboard shortcut to open the context menu on a tab in visual studio. I also looked at the keyboard shortcut options in tools/customise/context menus/other menus but couldn't see a suitable command to hook a shortcut onto. For example: right click/close all but this as a keyboard shortcut.