# Keyboard shortcut to close all tabs but pinned in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

If there are any ability to close all tabs except pinned in VS?

Comment: You may want to visit the Visual Studio user manual, as that is what I'm about to do to answer your question.  :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, bind a key to the OtherContextMenus.EasyMDIToolWindow.CloseAllButPinned command.

Tools > Options > Keyboard > bind the key using the interface.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to add that as a button on the toolbar? I can't find something relavant for "other context menus" or "easy mdi tool window" when i'm in add **Add Command** on customize toolbar.

Comment: This key is not there

Answer (score 5):

You can [use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to open the context menu for the active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580339/126014). Once you have the context menu open, you can use the arrow keys to select e.g. *Close All But Pinned*.

Some options on the context menu have underscores for faster access, such as e.g. *Close All But This*, which can be accessed with <kbd>a</kbd>, so that the entire sequence for *Close All But This* becomes <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to "Close All but this"; right click on tab and you can get that. Don't know whats a pinned tab in VS.

Comment: I don't know if it came after some update or I didn't notice it earlier, but I see close all but pinned option

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it without changing standard keyboard mapping is to right-click on any tab and select "Close all but pinned".

PS. The pinned windows functionality is part of visual studio productivity power tools.